# guzzle command post data

Tags: php, post, guzzle

How do i get post data through the guzzle service clients `getCommand` function?

my json looks like the following:

```
    "createMessage": {
        "httpMethod": "POST",
        "uri": "conversations/{conversation_id}/message",
        "summary": "conversations by user",
        "responseType": "class",
        "responseClass": "\\Conversations\\Message",
        "parameters": {
            "conversation_id": {
                "location": "uri",
                "description": "conversation id",
                "type": "integer"
             },
             "message": {
                 "location": "postField",
                 "sentAs": "message",
                 "type": "string"
             }
         }
     }
```

then i currently put my post data as part of the array passed through the getCommand:

```
$client = new \Guzzle\Service\Client();
$client->setDescription(\Guzzle\Service\Description\ServiceDescription::factory(__DIR__ . '/client.json'));
$command = $client->getCommand('createMessage', array('conversation_id' => 6, 'message' => 'test post message'));
```

it creates the new record in the database but the post data is empty so the `'message'` field is left empty.

i have tried setting `$client->setPostField('message', 'test post message');` but doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` appears to have done the trick, originally i had:

```
$command->set('command.headers', array('content-type' => 'application/json'));
```

However `POST` requests in `Guzzle` are sent with an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` Content-Type

```
$command->set('command.headers', array('content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
```

alternatively you can also do this in the json schema, setting a parameter of content-type:

```
"content-type": {
    "location": "header",
    "default": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 }
```